# Does Maven Execute Tests Differently When Running 'test' vs. 'install'?

Tags: java, maven-3

I have a JUnit test that fails when I execute:

```
$ mvn -U clean test
```

Yet, when I execute a build using `install`, it succeeds:

```
$ mvn -U clean install
```

**Question**:  Has anyone encountered this before, and if so, what could be causing this?

The code I am testing converts an entity hierarchy to a similar DTO hierarchy.  There is a mocked `Function`, which returns a `List` of 4 `Child` entities for a given `String`, injected into the class under test.

The failure occurs when the `List` of `ChildDTO` instances is obtained from the `ParentDTO`.  It *should* contain 4 `ChildDTO` instances, but instead is empty.

Using Maven 3.5.0

---

## **Sample Code**

### Entity Classes:

```
public class Child {
    private String name;
}

public class Parent {
    private List<Child> children;

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

For this discussion, assume the DTO classes closely match these entities.

### Class Under Test:

```
public class ThingToTest {

    @Autowired
    private Function<String, List<Child>> fetchChildren;

    public ParentDTO doSomething(Parent parent) {

        List<Child> childList = fetchChildren.apply("John");

        //  Convert to DTO representations

        return parentDto;
    }
}
```

### Unit Test in Question:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private Function<String, List<Child>> fetchChildren;

    @InjectMocks
    private ThingToTest thingToTest;

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {
        // Manually create a List of Child instances.
        List<Child> mockListOfChildren = generateChildren();

        // Mock the response to the Function's apply() method.
        Mockito.when(fetchChildren.apply("some-string")).thenReturn(mockListOfChildren);

        // Execute the code to be tested.
        ParentDTO parentDto = thingToTest.doSomething();
        assertNotNull(parentDto);

        List<ChildDTO> childList = parentDto.getChildren();
        assertNotNull(childList);
        assertEquals(4, childList.size());  //  <-  Fails here:  "expected:<4> but was:<0>"
}
```

Comment: No, the execution is identical, which suggests that you have a nondeterministic test. It may also be that your test structure is such that it's inadvertently order-dependent. As a note, using constructor injection will make your code easier to test.

Comment: As @chrylis says, there should be no difference.  Are you sure it's totally consistent that it succeeds if you stop at the 'test' and fails if you through to 'install', or could it be that it's more random than that?  How is **generateChildren()** defined? I'm guessing that the answer may lie therein.